# Adaptable at or in or to doing something

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I am confused with what is the correct expression to use, is it better saying "I am adaptable at using smth", "I am adaptable on using smth" or "I am adaptable to using smth"?

The third sounds completely wrong to me but a British guy said its the correct, I used the first but I am really confused so I want to hear opinions.

Comment: What is your quote trying to say?

Comment: Do you mean adept?

Answer (score 1):

If you say (1) "I am adaptable at using smth", it means that you can use smth in many different ways. If you say (2) "I am adaptable to using smth", it means that you have not previously used smth (perhaps you used jns to do the same thing), but that you could easily learn to use smth.  I would not use (3) "I am adaptable on using smth."  —this is ungrammatical.  But if you meant that you are not opposed to using smth, and could be persuaded to use it, you might say "I am FLEXIBLE on the QUESTION of [using/whether to use] smth." or "I am AMENABLE to using smth."

Answer (score 0):

The correct preposition to use with *[to be adaptable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adaptable)* is *to*.  The first and second examples are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your starting point is wrong, because it is not idiomatic English.

Instead, try:

> I can adapt to *X*

and

> I can adapt to using *X*

or, where the subject has less active involvement with the entity being used:

> I can adapt to the use of *X*

'To be adaptable ***to***' can be used in two different ways:

1) It implies that some entity is being passively adapted to some situation or process. Because living organisms cannot generally be treated this way, it is most often used with *inanimate nouns,* not *animate nouns:*

> This decor is adaptable to many different interior layouts
>
> The salary formula I'm using is adaptable to any size of workforce

(However, I think the following variation based on *adapt* sounds more natural:

> This decor can be adapted to many different interior layouts
>
> The salary formula I'm using can be adapted to any size of workforce)

2) It implies that some (generally animate) entity is actively capable of adapting to something:

> Rats are highly adaptable to different environments
>
> Dogs and children are both highly adaptable [= capable of adapting to new circumstances]